# Exponential Convexity Results

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convexity, convex-analysis

$\textbf{Definition:}$ 1. A function $h : (a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is exponentially convex if it is continuous
and
$$\sum _{i, j=1}^n\xi_i\xi_jh(x_i+x_j)\geq  0,$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all choices of $\xi_i,x_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $i = 1,\ldots ,n$, such that $x_i+x_j\in(a,b)$, $1 \leq i, j \leq n$.

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ Let $h:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The following propositions are equivalent.

(i) $h$ is exponentially convex.

(ii)$ h$ is continuous and
$$\sum _{i, j=1}^n\xi_i\xi_jh(\frac{x_i+x_j}{2})\geq  0,$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all choices of $\xi_i,x_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $i = 1, \ldots,n$, such that $x_i\in(a,b)$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.

The proof of above stated proposition is shown in this [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156730/exponential-convexity). This proposition is further followed by a corollary.

$\textbf{Corollary:}$ If $h$ is exponentially convex then
$$det\big[h\big(\frac{x_i+x_j}{2}\big)\big]_{i,j=1}^n\geq 0.$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_i\in(a,b)$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Can Someone help me to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Hint:** From the (ii), we will get the matrix $(h(\frac{x_i+x_j}{2}))_{i,j=1}^{n}$ is positive-definite matrix.

Comment: yes but I am looking for a formal proof.

Comment: @ShinningStar A matrix is positive is #http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#

Comment: you mean positive definite? Do we have some results the determinant of a positive definite matrix is positive? If you can give me some reference?

Comment: @ShinningStar You will find in the wiki about *characterizations's forth statement*  which I have given to you. The whole theorem is that **A matrix is positive-definite if and only if its leading principal minors are all positive.** So back to your question, the matrix in your corollary is a special leading principle minor.